# Excel comma data rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of data separated by comma in an excel sheet which needs to be converted into rows.
The data looks like this: ['C$ ', 'ADMIN$ ', 'WSTemp ', 'Disk #0, Partition #0 ']

there are 14000 cells (data separated by comma) to be converted into rows. I am using Data-> text to column function and then inverting/ transposing the data. But Anything quicker than this ? 
Thanks

Comment: Is the question about how to transpose the data; columns into rows?  If so, say so ... if not, then what is the question?

Comment: @rfornal there are 14000 cells (['C$ ', 'ADMIN$ ', 'WSTemp ', 'Disk #0, Partition #0 ']) to be converted into rows. I am using Data->  text to column function and then inverting/ transposing the data. But Anything quicker than this ? Thank you !

Comment: Is the data in Column A?

Comment: @PJRosenburg The data is spread across columns: AW to BC

Comment: I find it difficult to believe a VBA macro could be faster than the equivalent Excel function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need VBA in order to do this. If you go to the "Data" tab in Excel and go to the "data tools" section, there is an option that is called text to columns. Click on that and you can tell the function what you want to split each line of text by. In this case it would be the ",". This is specific to Microsoft 2013. I know this functionality exists in 2010, though it might not be called text to columns. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you @Thomas Beck Sutton. I am doing that. But the 'comma data ' is over a thousand cells. I am looking for a faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is working in VBA.

Start by looping over the source data.

Using Split, Build an array of the items in the cell, then using UBound to get the amount of items in the array. 
Remove any additional quotes, so you don't have to later.

**TESTED:**

**This is the revised answer: V4**

```
Sub CellSplitToRows()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim tempVals() As String
Dim valCount As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim newLast As Long
Dim lastSourceRow As Long

lastSourceRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "AW").End(xlUp).row

For r = 2 To lastSourceRow
    For lCol = 49 To 55     'Columns AW to BC
        tempVals() = Split(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, lCol).Text, ",")
        valCount = UBound(tempVals) + 1      '+1 for Array index 0
        i = 0
        lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "BE").End(xlUp).row
        newLast = lastRow + valCount
        For lRow = (lastRow + 1) To newLast
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lRow, "BE") = Replace(tempVals(i), "'", "") 'Remove Single Quotes
            i = i + 1
        Next lRow
    Next lCol
Next r
End Sub
```

[image: V4]

Comment: Thank you @PJ Rosenburg. I want the data in rows. So Im editing out your formula to: Sub CellSplitToColumns()

Comment: Where SPECIFICALLY do you want the rows?  The source is column AW to BC?  So each of those columns has a cell with multiple comma separated text?  and you are putting it into rows below?

Comment: So I have data from AW-BC. I want the data in (AW,3) to be under the rows of column BE

Comment: Sorry. But Im unable to attach a picture(I dont have the reqd points). I will work on the code that you provided. Thank you. I will let you know of the result.

Comment: Got that. I'm working around it. Will update you. Thank you @ P J Rosenburg.

Comment: @Rush, updated and I think without seeing your source, this is the most I can do with it.  It's going to just keep adding everything down the end of BE.  So every row that has anything in it from AW to BC will get Split and listed as a separate cell, thus multiplying the amount of rows your sheet has by about 35 times.  
By now, I'm sure you're pretty intimate with the few simple commands I've used, and the looping concepts are very flexible.  So with your knowledge of the situation, you are probably going to get it.

Comment: Is it possible that you want AW to go to BE, and AX to BF, AY to BG, etc?